# PyInstaller 2.1 IOError Windows-32bit run.exe

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

Suddenly, PyInstaller 2.1 will not build my project.  It had no issue a short time ago, and there is not apparent explanation.  It throws an IOError saying my Windows-32bit run.exe is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a damn Windows 10 update!  Windows Defender now considers some of the PyInstaller exe's to be malware!  So, it automatically deleted these required files.  Those bastards!

To solve this, I added the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\PyInstaller-2.1\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit` where the files are being deleted from as a Windows Defender exclusion. Here's how:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/instantanswers/64495205-6ddb-4da1-8534-1aeaf64c0af8/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-defender-antivirus

Luckily, I had the same files on Windows 8 machine, so I just copied them from there and dropped them in place.  If you don't have that, you'll probably need to reinstall PyInstaller.

I also need to turn off Windows Defender to run my build process, else it continued to have errors.  You may need to do that first to reinstall the program.